# Order of imported css file in component - vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have the main.js for the main entry point of my app and I import an app.scss. It holds my global css like bootstrap, font-awesome and etc.

```
/* Vue */
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'
// import store from './store'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* App sass */
import './assets/style/app.scss';

/* App component */
import App from './components/App'


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    // Attach the Vue instance to the window,
    // so it's available globally.
    created: function () {
        window.Vue = this
    },
    router,
    // store,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

In one of my component, I imported another .scss files something like this:

```
import '../../../assets/style/echelon/base-user-main.scss';
import '../../../assets/style/echelon/base-helper.scss';
```

But when the page renders to the browser, that order is in reverse. the app.scss that was imported in my main.js(entry point of the app) was below the .scss of my component something like this:

```
<style>
/* Content of base-user-main.scss */
</style>

<style>
/* Content of base-helper.scss */
</style>

<style>
/* Content of app.scss */
</style>
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Import your `'./assets/style/app.scss'` inside your **App** component and not in your **main.js** file

Comment: @ what about vendor css? e.g. `'node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'`

Comment: Import it there as well

Comment: how would you do it in App.vue? I've tried it, it works from assets folder but not from node_modules.

Comment: inside the style tag: `@import "node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min"`(note no .css extension)